# ArrayList seems not to contain anything

Tags: java, local-variables

In my application user has to enter in the console name, username and password. Later the program should check the login to the involvement of a dynamic array, and if not it there, add it, and if it is, display an error warning.
When you run, an input box, where quietly entered above "name", "username" and "password". However, the program does not make login check for involvement in the array and displays an error message, as well, it does not take themselves array field.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class User  {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader bReader =new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String name = bReader.readLine();
        String login = bReader.readLine();
        String password = bReader.readLine();
        UserADD(name,login,password);

    }
    public static ArrayList<String> UserADD(String name,String login,String password) {
        ArrayList <String> users = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int i = 0; i<users.size(); i++) {
            if (users.contains(login)) {
                System.out.println("Это имя пользователя уже занято");
            }
            else users.add(name);

            users.add(login);
            users.add(password);

            System.out.println(users);
        }

        return users;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the error message

Comment: Because `users` is always empty. You are creating a local variable everytime you call the method `UserADD`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `ArrayList<String> users` is method local. This means that every time you call the method another object gets created and it's initially empty.

The possible solution would be to create an `ArrayList` in `main` method and pass it as an argument to `userAdd()`.

As you are learning `Java` please try to follow best practices. Don't start function names with a capital letter. They're reserved for class names.

Answer (score 0):

ArrayList `users` is local under `UserADD` method.
Declare ArrayList `users` as global will fix the problem.

```
public class User  {

//Global declaration of ArrayList users
public static ArrayList <String> users = new ArrayList<String>();

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader bReader =new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String name = bReader.readLine();
    String login = bReader.readLine();
    String password = bReader.readLine();
    UserADD(name,login,password);

}
public static ArrayList<String> UserADD(String name,String login,String password) {
    //don't initialize users ArrayList here
    for (int i = 0; i<users.size(); i++) {
        if (users.contains(login)) {
            System.out.println("Это имя пользователя уже занято");
        }
        else users.add(name);   users.add (login);users.add(password);

        System.out.println(users);
}


    return users;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to hold the users in a class object to live longer than the function call. A bit like:

```
public class UserRegistration  {

    private List<String> users = new ArrayList<>();

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    new UserRegistration().run();
}

private void run() {
    BufferedReader bReader =new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String name = bReader.readLine();
    String login = bReader.readLine();
    String password = bReader.readLine();
    addUser(name,login,password);
}

public boolean addUser(String name,String login,String password) {
    for (int i = 0; i<users.size(); i++) {
        if (users.contains("\t" + login + "\t")) {
            System.out.println("Это имя пользователя уже занято");
            return false;
        }
    }
    users.add(name + "\t" + login + "\t" +  password);
    return true;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution will be

```
public class User {

    Set<UserLogin> users = new HashSet<UserLogin>();

    public static void main(String[] arg) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader bReader =new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String name = bReader.readLine();
        String login = bReader.readLine();
        String password = bReader.readLine();
        new User().UserADD(new User(). new UserLogin(name, login, password));                
    }

    private void UserADD(final UserLogin user) {

        if (!users.contains(user)) {
            users.add(user);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Это имя пользователя уже занято");
        }
    }

    public class UserLogin {

        private String name;
        private String login;
        private String pass;

        public UserLogin(String name, String login, String pass) {
            this.name = name;
            this.login = login;
            this.pass = pass;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public String getLogin() {
            return login;
        }

        public String getPass() {
            return pass;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (this == o) return true;
            if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

            UserLogin user = (UserLogin) o;

            return !(login != null ? !login.equals(user.login) : user.login != null);

        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return login != null ? login.hashCode() : 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all very much, but the problem remained. When you try to second user to input a username first, the program accepts it calmly, ignoring any restrictions and a warning on the screen does not come out. I tried all the options.